# Is using of delete operator correct in here I'm confused

Tags: c++

I'm just a beginner at C++ and today while we are learning about linked list my teacher showed us how to delete from front at the linked list.The problem is I didn't understand why we are deleting pointer p which is static memory can't we just do it with second code that uses dynamic memory pointer which is temp? Head is dynamic memory pointer for object of type Node

```
//My teacher code 
template <class T>
void DeleteFront(Node<T>* & head)
{
    // save the address of node to be deleted
    Node<T> *p = head;

    // make sure list is not empty
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        // move head to second node and delete original
        head = head->NextNode();
        delete p;//I didn't understand this line because our p declaration is static 
    }
}
```

```cpp
//My suggestion
template <class T>
void DeleteFront(Node<T>* & head)
{
    // save the address of node to temporary dynamic pointer
    Node<T> *temp ;
    temp=new Node<T>(head);

    // make sure list is not empty
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        // move temp to second node which will be showed by head
        temp = head->NextNode();
        delete head;//delete front item
        head=temp;//assign the address of second node to head
    }
}
```

Comment: But `p` is not static? Basically, all you did was renaming variables and leaking memory allocated for `temp`.

Comment: 1) Please provide [mre] instead of descriptions of code. It's unclear what do you mean by "_why we are deleting pointer p which is static_". 2) Your suggestion does exactly the same thing (functionally), but, in addition to that, leaks memory.

Comment: It would help if you formatted your code for readability and if you removed the whole `template ...` stuff first, unless it really is relevant. For code questions, you should aim at a [mcve]. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: `p` is not declared static, but automatic (local) variable. It is used the same way you used your `temp` variable. Except you allocated memory for `temp` that is leaked.

Comment: For your suggestion: If you already want to delete, why do you further allocate?

Comment: Looks like you do not understand how pointers work, When you assign one pointer to another you just make them point to the same thing. When you call `delete` you are not deleting pointer itself, you are deleting the object where it points to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

p is not declared static. In fact it's a local variable. Static variables can only be declared in class scope, and are marked with the keyword `static`.
A static variable is a variable that is accessible independently of any objects and is valid for the class itself, having the same value for any object, or even without any objects. This is not the case, it's a very normal local variable, which resides on the stack and holds the pointer to a Node object.
When you call delete on that pointer, you delete what the pointer points to, not the pointer object on the stack itself. The pointer itself of course also has an address, which you would get with `&p` and could be saved into a `Node<T>**` variable. Though there is no need to do that. Calling delete on an object that is on the stack doesn't work.

Now regarding the code:

You are creating a new node with

```
Node<T> *temp ;
temp=new Node<T>(head);
```

which is not only unnecessary but in fact you are leaking memory, since you override the pointer value or exit the function without calling `delete`.
Every new should have a corresponding delete, at least when the pointer goes out of scope, such as the end of your function. The line is completely superfluous. A better way to initialize your a pointer is:

```
Node<T> *temp = nullptr;
```

Other than that, your code does the same thing. your teacher saves what is to be deleted into p, which works but might seem unintuitive, while you save what is to be saved (`head->NextNode()`). Both work.
Also `NextNode()` is a function and should have a lower case name. A function's name should also imply what it does. While this is easy enough to know in this case, NextNode isn't really a verb/action. `getNextNode()` would be a better name.

To improve on your teacher's code you could put the declaration of p into the if-block and save the `p = head` as well as the stack operations if the list is not empty, but I'm sure the compiler would do that for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Node<T> *p = head;

// make sure list is not empty
if (head != NULL)
{
    // move head to second node and delete original
    head = head->NextNode();
    delete p;
}
```

This section of code assigns the pointer p to the head passed into it. It then checks if the head is NULL, and if it is not then it moves the head to the next node before deleting p -- which is not a static. It is local, but not static. This removes the original head from memory and removes most chances at a dangling pointer.

```
Node<T> *temp ;
temp=new Node<T>(head);

if (head != NULL)
{

    temp = head->NextNode();
    delete head;
    head=temp;
}
```

This code deletes the original head after assigning the head to a temp object, then passes the object back to head. It does not delete the temp Node object. This would be a potential dangling reference, as the head is getting passed by address and the original address was never deleted when held by temp.